# (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE) vs Accountmanager.get(context)

Tags: android, account, accountmanager, android-account

What's the difference between -

```
AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
```

and

```
AccountManager accountManager =Accountmanager.get(context)
```

What should i use when-

1.Retrieving list of already created accounts in device

2.Adding my app's account to device

Answer (score 2):

If you look into `Accountmanager.get(context)` you'll see that it's basically a shortcut to first option with null check:

```
public static AccountManager get(Context context) {
    if (context == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("context is null");
    return (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
}
```